# getting "command not found: phalcon" after successfully installing phalcon/devtools via composer

Tags: command-line, composer-php, phalcon, phalcon-devtools

```
Software: MacOS
Phalcon: 5.0.0RC4
Phalcon/Devtools: 4.2.0
```

I have newly created phalcon 5.0 repository.
I successfully ran

```
composer install
composer require phalcon/devtools
```

however when I try to run a phalcon command I get

```
zsh: command not found: phalcon
```

I checked if it had installed successfully and tried reinstalling as well.
php -m returns that phalcon is installed too:

```
php -m | grep phalcon
phalcon
```

and the extension is there in the php.ini file

```
extension="phalcon.so"
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `phalcon/devtools` package links the `phalcon.php` executable to your composer `bin-dir`.

Get it as follows:

```
composer config bin-dir
```

It defaults to `./vendor/bin`. The installed symlink is `./vendor/bin/phalcon.php`.

You can run the command as follows:

```
./vendor/bin/phalcon.php [..]
```

To ease access you can automatically add `./vendor/bin` to your `PATH` (i.e. with [direnv](https://direnv.net/))

```
# .envrc
PATH_add ./vendor/bin
```

or you can create a `./bin` dir in your project directory and symlink `phalcon.php` as `phalcon` into it.

```
mkdir ./bin
ln -sfn ./vendor/bin/phalcon.php ./bin/phalcon
```

Now you can add `./bin` to your `PATH`:

```
export PATH="${PWD}/bin:${PATH}"
```

And invoke the phalcon CLI with:

```
phalcon [..]
```

Comment: Thanks! quick not that for me the path was ```./vendor/bin/phalcon``` without the ```php```. Also there was still an issue of compatibility between phalcon 5 and devtools 4.2, so the command still did not run.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Nicolai's answer, it is also possible to just call phalcon like so:

```
vendor/bin/phalcon commands
```

In my case, I didn't want to be able to call phalcon globally so I copied the file into the project directory and named it `phalcon4`
Then I edited the paths inside the file like so

```
$addpath = '/vendor/phalcon';
$GLOBALS['_composer_bin_dir'] = __DIR__ .$addpath;
$GLOBALS['_composer_autoload_path'] = __DIR__ .$addpath. '/..'.'/autoload.php';

// the rest of the code

include __DIR__ .$addpath. '/..'.'/phalcon/devtools/phalcon';
```

Now I can run the command like this:

```
php phalcon4 commands
```

Still, devtools 4.2 cannot run with phalcon 5 so the command just threw an error.